# Scala partition into more than two lists

Tags: list, scala

I have a list in Scala that I'm trying to partition into multiple lists based on a predicate that involves multiple elements of the list. For example, if I have

```
a: List[String] = List("a", "ab", "b", "abc", "c")
```

I want to get `b: List[List[String]]` which is a List of `List[String]` such that the sum of the lengths of the inner `List[String] == 3`. i.e `List(List("a", "b", "c"), List("abc"), List("ab", "a"), ...)`

[Edit] Needs to take a reasonable time for lists of length 50 or less.

Answer (score 2):

Build all possible sublists and filter:

```
def filter[A](list: List[A])(predicate: (List[A] => Boolean)): List[List[A]] = {
  (for {i <- 1 to list.length
        subList <- list.combinations(i)
        if predicate(subList)
  } yield subList).toList
}

val a = List("a", "ab", "b", "abc", "c")

val result = filter(a)(_.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.length) == 3)
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit too inefficient for my purposes, it gets slow extremely quickly.

Comment: Hm. You didn't define any performance requirements. So I'm really don't understand your downvote.

Comment: Sorry :) So update your post with performance requirements or other.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to build an efficient algorithm that is cheaper than `O(2^n * O(p))` for any arbitrary predicate, `p`. This is because every subset must be evaluated. You will never achieve something that works for `n == 50`.

Answer (score 2):

I think **Sergey** is on a good track here, but we can optimize his code a little bit. First of all, we can notice that if the sum of string lengths is N then for sure we don't need to check combinations composed of more than N strings, as the shortest string is at least one character long. And, additionally, we can get away without **for** synctatic sugar and use the **sum** method instead of a much more generic (and thus, probably, not so quick) **foldLeft**.

For clarity's sake, let's first define a small helper function which will compute the sum of strings lengths:

```
def sumOfStr(list: List[String]) = list.map(_.length).sum
```

And now the main method:

```
def split(list: List[String], sum: Int) = 
  (1 to sum).map(list.combinations(_).filter(sumOfStr(_) == sum)).flatten.toList
```

**EDIT**: With our powers combined, we give you a still very inefficient, but hey-that's-the-best-we-can-do-in-reasonable-time version:

```
def sumOfStr(lst: List[String]) = {
  var sum = 0
  lst.foreach{ sum += _.length }
  sum  
}

def split(lst: List[String], sum: Int) = 
  (1 to sum).par
  .map(lst.combinations(_).filter(sumOfStr(_) == sum))
  .flatten.toList
```

Comment: `list.view.map(_.length).sum` would be even faster. The `.map` causes a new List to be constructed that gets thrown away immediately.

Comment: @nate, possibly, but needs measuring. `.view` has an overhead too.

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty test that shows the time differences. It seems like times vary, but on average `.view` is slightly faster than without. `.iterator` is slightly faster than `.view`. Unrolling it is always faster. https://gist.github.com/nbauernfeind/43f3ac146368d166531d

Comment: I modified the gist to sum length of strings (which is a constant time operation instead of `list.length` which is `O(n)`). For some reason `.iterator` is consistently slower than `.view`.

Comment: Thanks, Nate :) Actually, on my computer, `view` is quite faster than `iterator`: 3.0s to 3.8s . And anyway `unrolled` beats all.

Comment: Also, if we change `(1 to sum).map(...)` to `(1 to sum).par.map(...)` it may save as a few seconds. In my test I used an input list of length 50 with string of lengths ranging from 3 to 20 and I wanted to split it with sum=12. Without `par` it took me 37s, with `par` 30.5s. But it's still very inefficient... Maybe if I write my own implementation of a function which would combine `combinations` and `filter` it would be faster... uhmmm, no.